# Is it possible to pass property value to annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I want to get this, is it possible?

```
@Autowired
lateinit var config : AppProperties

@RabbitListener(queues = ["#{\${config.queueName}}"])
fun listen(message: String?) {
    println(message)
}
```

> Could not resolve placeholder 'config.queueName' in value "#{${config.queueName}}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible in this case, because Spring doesn't know about "config", but you can use SPeL for retrieving property from AppProperties bean, for example:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = ["#{appProperties.queueName}"])
```

It should work if your @Autowired AppProperties has bean name = 'appProperties'

I can't check this solution at this moment, but i think that it should work.

**UPD:**

You can use this soltuion without defining *config* variable, because  SPeL working with beans and defining *config* variable unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this value is coming from a properties file. I have not used kotlin but this is how we do in java.

**application.yml**

```
config:
  queueName: somequeue
```

**Code:**

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${config.queueName}")
fun listen(message: String?) {
    println(message)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@RabbitListener(queues = ["\${config.queueName}"])
```

please try like this, you can read about that more at this [blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/10/spring-kotlin-references-in-value-annotation/)